# Does death affect drop rate of legendary in nephalem rift?

Tags: diablo-iii

My friend told me the longer I survive in battle the more likely legendary drops, and death will reset the timer,is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, death does not affect your legendary drop rate.  There indeed is a "timer" so people won't  get frustrated for not getting a legendary. This timer tick only **when you are fighting monsters** (so idling in base won't get you a legendary), it is made so no player can fight for more than 10 hours without finding one. Nothing reset the timer except finding a legendary.

You can refer to [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11987068820) and [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11911261013#3) for more information about it.

Comment: Do you have a source of it being reset on game restart? If it really is, busy people who play for a hour at a time are basically exempt from this system, and can still play for 10 one-hour sessions and not get a legendary. Right?

Comment: @OrcJMR Well apparently I was mistaken and it does not. Ill edit that

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a long-standing idea that legendary drops are based on a timer, which is completely false.

Comment: technically there is a timer but it doesn't affect anything 99.9% of the time http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/2168xn/there_seems_to_be_a_lot_of_misinformation_about/

Comment: @z- The reason for this "timer" is so people don't play for 10 hours and never get a legendary. Staying alive has nothing to do with your chances of finding legendaries.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't meant to imply that the timer is a death timer.